# Sending Email Via Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, email, kotlin, jakarta-mail

I am using the code below to send an email but it is asking for gmail credentials. I am looking for a command, something similar to mailx, to send emails to a particular address without asking for any credentials. Any help is appreciated.

**Code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val editTextTo: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTo)

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val to = editTextTo.getText().toString()
            val subject = "Test"
            val message = "Test"

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            val addressees = arrayOf(to)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressees)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            intent.setType("message/rfc822")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"));
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't send an email, it opens the default email app installed with pre-filled data and the user is the one who sends the email.

Comment: And it is asking for Gmail credentials because probably Gmail app is installed without a configured account, try setting the credentials and report back the behavior.

Comment: Is there any way to send email without gmail app like mailx in unix commands

Comment: You can use [JavaMail](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), but you won't be able to impersonate the user, you'll need to use your own SMPT server

Comment: mailx can't send directly to Gmail.  mailx only works without a password if it sends to your local mail server, which trusts you because you're on your private intranet.  If there was a mail server on the public internet that allowed people to send email without a password, can you imagine how spammers would abuse that?  Including your password for your Gmail account in your application is risky because someone could discover it and abuse your account.

Answer (score -1):

There is a java solution try to make your kotlin one(sorry I'm not into Kotlin).

Add this to your gradle

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
```

and add those two [classes](https://gist.github.com/oussemaAr/50b6189955f6036ebfdb0bacdc433bf4) one for creating the SMTP server and the other for security purpose and call it like this:

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                        "you_email@gmail.com",
                        "password");

sender.sendMail(subject, message,sender,recipients);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oussema Aroua for your comment. Do I need to enter password here? I am working on contact us page that need to send email once the form data has been submitted. If I enter credentials then its not secured.

Comment: you need to type the email, I was putting the encrypted password inside the gradle file then decryption it at run type

Comment: At an other application I made the mail send through the Api

Comment: I am not getting any error in my log but at the same time, I am not getting any email too. Below is the code outline. class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val sender = GMailSender(
"contact@gmail.com",
"Hello")
val subject="Test" val message="Test Message"
val recipients="test@gmail.com"
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
sender.sendMail(subject, message, sender.toString(), recipients)
}) }}

Comment: I am facing an error     on line:  Transport.send(message)        in GMailSender class  
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain' appears in /data/app/~~r8aMnomVmYs6XTttCAzxuA==/com.checkmed.rider-jrpxzSTSRa0OvYPz9-bPDQ==/base.apk)